CMakeList.txt,,,,target "cpr::cpr" not found
I finished installing influxdb on my Raspberry Pi and now I want to communicate with influxdb via C++, so I did git clone https://github.com/offa/influxdb-cxx
but I keep getting an error that it can't find the cpr::cpr target.
and also i tried
git clone https://github.com/libcpr/cpr.git
but after this
When I enter the cmake .. command (in cd ~/influxdb-cxx/build), the following error appears:
-- ~~~ influxdb-cxx v0.7.1 ~~~
-- Build Type : RelWithDebInfo
-- Boost support : ON
-- Unit Tests : ON
-- System Tests : ON
-- Found cpr: /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcpr.so  
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:44 (add_library):
  Target "InfluxDB" links to target "cpr::cpr" but the target was not found.
  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
  ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at test/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "LineProtocolTest" links to target "cpr::cpr" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  test/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_unittest)


CMake Error at test/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "LineProtocolTest" links to target "cpr::cpr" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  test/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_unittest)

This is CMakeList.txt in ~/influx-cxx
####################################
# General project definition
####################################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.0)

# disable testsuite when included
# using add_subdirectory
if(DEFINED PROJECT_NAME)
  set(INCLUDED_AS_SUBPROJECT ON)
  set(INFLUXCXX_TESTING OFF CACHE BOOL "testing not available in sub-project")
  set(INFLUXCXX_SYSTEMTEST OFF CACHE BOOL "system testing not available in sub-project")
  set(INFLUXCXX_COVERAGE OFF CACHE BOOL "coverage not available in sub-project")
endif()

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared versions of libraries" ON)
option(INFLUXCXX_WITH_BOOST "Build with Boost support enabled" ON)
option(INFLUXCXX_TESTING "Enable testing for this component" ON)
option(INFLUXCXX_SYSTEMTEST "Enable system tests" ON)
option(INFLUXCXX_COVERAGE "Enable Coverage" OFF)

# Define project
project(influxdb-cxx
  VERSION 0.7.1
  DESCRIPTION "InfluxDB C++ client library"
  LANGUAGES CXX
)

message(STATUS "~~~ ${PROJECT_NAME} v${PROJECT_VERSION} ~~~")


# Add compiler flags for warnings
if(NOT MSVC AND NOT INCLUDED_AS_SUBPROJECT)
    add_compile_options(-Wall
      -Wextra
      -pedantic
      -pedantic-errors
      -Werror
      -Wshadow
      -Wold-style-cast
      -Wnull-dereference
      -Wnon-virtual-dtor
      -Woverloaded-virtual
      )
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
# We explicitly export the public interface
set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
set(CMAKE_VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN 1)
include(GenerateExportHeader)

# Set fPIC for all targets
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

# Set the default build type to "RelWithDebInfo"
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE AND NOT CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RelWithDebInfo"
    CACHE
    STRING "Choose the type of build, options are: Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel."
    FORCE
  )
endif()

message(STATUS "Build Type : ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
message(STATUS "Boost support : ${INFLUXCXX_WITH_BOOST}")
message(STATUS "Unit Tests : ${INFLUXCXX_TESTING}")
message(STATUS "System Tests : ${INFLUXCXX_SYSTEMTEST}")


# Add coverage flags
if(INFLUXCXX_COVERAGE)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --coverage")
endif()

####################################
# Dependencies
####################################

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(cpr REQUIRED)

if (INFLUXCXX_WITH_BOOST)
    # Fixes warning when using boost from brew
    set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED TRUE)

    find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
endif()

add_subdirectory(3rd-party)

####################################
# Library
####################################

# Create library
# note: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS specifies if static or shared
#       as boost is build without -fPIC, we cannot
#       statically link against it when building
#       influxdb as shared object
add_subdirectory("src")


####################################
# Tests
####################################

if (INFLUXCXX_TESTING)
  enable_testing()
  add_subdirectory("test")
endif()


####################################
# Install
####################################

include(GNUInstallDirs)

# Build targets with install rpath on Mac to dramatically speed up installation
# https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
list(FIND CMAKE_PLATFORM_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}" isSystemDir)
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Darwin")
  if("${isSystemDir}" STREQUAL "-1")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path/../${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}")
  endif()
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
endif()
unset(isSystemDir)

# Install library
install(TARGETS InfluxDB
  EXPORT InfluxDBTargets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

# Create version file
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/InfluxDBConfigVersion.cmake"
  VERSION ${PACKAGE_VERSION}
  COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

# Install headers
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}")
install(FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src/influxdb_export.h DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}")

# Export targets
install(EXPORT InfluxDBTargets
  FILE
    InfluxDBTargets.cmake
  NAMESPACE
    InfluxData::
  DESTINATION
    ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/InfluxDB
)

# Configure and install Config files
configure_package_config_file(
  cmake/InfluxDBConfig.cmake.in cmake/InfluxDBConfig.cmake
  INSTALL_DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/InfluxDB"
  PATH_VARS CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
)

install(
  FILES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/InfluxDBConfig.cmake"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/InfluxDBConfigVersion.cmake"
  DESTINATION
    ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/InfluxDB
)

I don't know what's wrong, please help me

How did you build and install cpr on your machine?

And what is the contents of cprTargets.cmake if you installed it via CMake?

find_package(cpr REQUIRED) can use either Findcpr.cmake script (in MODULE mode) or cprConfig.cmake one (in CONFIG mode). There is no Findcpr.cmake script shipped with CMake itself, and project influxdb-cxx doesn't provide that script either. So it seems the project expects cprConfig.cmake script to be executed. That script is actually provided with installation of cpr project... But the output like -- Found cpr: /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcpr.so is never produced in CONFIG mode of find_package.

It smells like you have manually installed Findcpr.cmake script into CMake directory. So exactly that script is executed during the find_package(cpr REQUIRED). Given script doesn't create cpr::cpr imported target, as influxdb-cxx project expects, thus you got the error. It is greatly discouraged to add custom Find*.cmake scripts into CMake directory.

Can you can a GitHub issue with https://github.com/offa/influxdb-cxx ?
